# How to split Ruby code as in C or C++ code

Tags: ruby

I'd like to split a long piece of Ruby code into multiple Ruby source files. In C source file, I can put the code like this:

**a.c**

```c
switch (n) {
    case 1:
        printf("1\n");
        break;
#include "b.c"
}
```

**b.c**

```c
    case 2:
        printf("2\n");
        break;
```

In Ruby, I can't do it like that:

**a.rb**

```rb
case n
when 1
  puts "1"
load "b.rb" # or include
end
```

**b.rb**

```rb
when 2
  puts "2"
```

How do I write it in Ruby code just like in C source file?

Comment: This smells like an X-Y-question to me. What you want to do is impossible in Ruby. What you want to *achieve* is very likely possible in Ruby, but you need to tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: C's `#include` is a preprocessor directive which causes the line to be _replaced_ by the given source file, prior to compilation. Ruby doesn't have this kind of inclusion mechanism.

Comment: @Stefan Unless you use something like ERB.

Comment: I've changed your example code to make the C and Ruby snippets more alike. Hope I didn't change the meaning of your question.

Comment: BTW, I don't think splitting your C code (or any code) that way is a good idea in the first place. Ripping apart logical units makes your code much harder to read / understand / maintain.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, i know about that "include" in C code was ugly but that was i need to do in my ruby code. because I wrote the server logic code from incoming client's protocals and select some "cases" to do something, now I have more than 30 "when" in a long ruby logic code, it was hard to read if I continuing add more and more "when" in ruby file. so I think would if I can split the code into different source files just like: database_operate.rb, coins_calculate.rb ...  etc...

Comment: @DarkSpy that's what Jörg W Mittag meant with [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/391826): instead of asking how to split up a huge `case-when` construct (your actual problem), you asked how to replicate C's `#include` in Ruby (your attempt to solve it). That's unfortunate because your actual problem is quite interesting and non-trivial. You should incorporate your comment into your question and mention that `#include`-idea only briefly. (given the downvotes and answers in the wrong direction you may want to delete this question and post a new one)

Answer (score 0):

When you use method `load` in ruby, the whole file is read by the interpreter and is executed by it. But it should be valid syntax by itself.

For example you can do like this:

file1.rb:

```
puts 'I am in file1'
```

file2.rb:

```
case condition
when "a"
  load 'file1.rb'
when "b"
  puts 'I am in main file'
end
```

But I don't recommend doing this. It's better to split code into meaningful classes/modules and then require files/include modules when needed.

Ruby has great support of OOP so you can get advantage of it

Comment: The OP also wants to extract then `when`-part into the other file.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "valid syntax of the first file."

Comment: @sawa probably that you can't `load` a file having invalid syntax (e.g. `when` without `case`) without causing an exception.

Comment: @Stefan Something like "syntactically valid when interpreted in the context of the first file"?

Comment: @sawa I don't think the context is taken into account, is it? The syntax is either valid or not.

Comment: @Stefan I meant that `when ...` is invalid when isolated, by valid when placed within `case ... end`.

Comment: @sawa that's what I meant too :-) You could also say that that you can `load` a file without getting `SyntaxError` if `ruby -c file1.rb` says "Syntax OK". In any case, each file has to be syntactically valid on its own, so you can't decompose an expression into smaller fragments and assemble it later that way.

Comment: @Stefan: It does not only need to be syntactically valid, it needs to be semantically valid as well. `load` and `require` simply run the file. Nothing more. Therefore, the file has to be runnable, working, valid, correct, Ruby code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag of course, but that would result in other errors. Although, maybe it doesn't make much sense to emphasis the separate stages of parsing and evaluation, and just accept that `load` may result in exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a fully object-oriented language. Even when you are writing code at the top of a file, it's actually run *in* the `Object` object.

The easiest way to actually split an apparently imperative procedural code is to put the code in a method somewhere else, so it gets a namespace.

A kind-of solution for your case is:

```
# a.rb

require_relative 'b'


case condition
when "a"
  puts "a"
when ->(it) { B.handle?(it) }
  B.handle(condition)
end


# b.rb

module B
  def self.handle?(cond)
    "b" === cond
  end

  def self.handle(cond)
    case cond
    when "b"
      puts "we are in b.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that being object oriented is relevant to the included code being executed in the main/Object environment.

Comment: In my opinion, it is relevant, because the code that was apparently written "at the top level" is actually run "in some object". Failing to understand it is what leads the OP to think that one could just include files as if they were C code.